# how to save user in mongoose hook using middleware

Tags: node.js, mongoose, audit-logging

I am using this library [Mongoose Audit Plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-audit)
and I have added this snippet in my entity schema:

```
let AuditLog = require('mongoose-audit')

GiftSchema.virtual('Author').set(function (userEmail) {
  this._user = userEmail
})
```

Middleware code look like this but it's not saving user in auditlog collection.

```
var updated = _.merge({}, req.body, {
          Author: req.decoded.user
        })
```

Any suggestions?
I have also used this package but it didn't save any record in DB. [mongoose-audit-log](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-audit-log)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
req.body = _.merge({}, req.body, {
   Author: req.decoded.user
})
```

Resolved. I just merged the body in request instead of updated variable